# Seach file in subdirectories in C++ while the parent directory path contains wild characters '.'

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io

I'm looking for d3d11.pdb symbol file at path "C:\symbols\d3d11.pdb\3ABF1DF9355C4FF69983BB73D2411E6C1\d3d11.pdb", here the hash part varies with runtime package.

when I use this function FindFirstFile in C++, I pass “C:\symbols\d3d11.pdb” as parent directory, but it considers the directory name as file and return the handle for the same.
reference link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Any solution or other approach you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching, you should specify a wildcard: `“C:\symbols\d3d11.pdb\*.*`

Comment: - I'm using the example code from the msdn link. your suggestion is returning this output

"The first file found is ."

- It means it is searching for files in the directory “C:\symbols\d3d11.pdb" only, while we want to go one level ahead.

Comment: @Xdev: Obviously you find the `.` and `..` links. You will also find that varying hash part. Once you have that, you can check directly if `C:\symbols\d3d11.pdb\<hash>\d3d11.pdb` exists.

Comment: Ahh! you meant using FindNextFile() function. That was really helpful. Thank you so much. Cheers!

Comment: @Xdev: Sorry, I assumed that you already knew that `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` are almost always used in combination. The reason is that you want to define the search once but get multiple results back.

Comment: Yes I didn't the combination of both the functions till yesterday. No worries! Thanks!